# react page showing allrecordings.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have create a page in react js to show list of all the recordings. It also has a view recording button in a table. When I click on view recording button it redirects to another page which show  the particular recording data.

now when I click again on all recordings button in side menu it show me the error allrecordings.map is not a function, but when I refresh the page error goes.

question is why does it heppens that refreshing the page loads the data when sudden click show error.  I am new to react so any one who can guide me on this.

Comment: Sounds like `allrecordings` might not be an array at the point you are calling `map`, but without seeing the code this is pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: Could you bring us a code snippet showing how you load the recordings? They might be undefined when you tried to map them

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7b1gj54a/

Comment: above is the code snippet to show how I am using allrecordings.map

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is asynchronous and has no value at the moment...
Use the condition that you do not have an error when there is no data yet

```
allRecordings ? allRecordings.map((item, index) => {
                   let cdate = item.recorded_dt;
                       var  d = cdate.split('T')[0];


                 return (


                  <tr key={(item.id)}>  
                    
                    <td>{ item.id}</td>
                    <td>{ (item.clientname) ? item.clientname : "n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.companyname) ? item.companyname : "n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.recorded_dt) ? d :"n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.file_length_min) ? item.file_length_min :"n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.signal_quality) ? item.signal_quality : "n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.HR_bpm) ? item.HR_bpm : "n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.name) ? item.name :"n/a" }</td>
                    <td><button onClick={() => this.fetchREcordingJson(item.id) }>View Recording</button> </td>
                    
                  </tr>  
                  

                  );

                } :[]
```

or

```
allRecordings && allRecordings.length!=0 ? allRecordings.map((item, index) => {
////some code
}:[]
```

Or put it equal to the array at the beginning of the component
in classComponent:

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
allRecordings :[]
}
}
```

in functioComponent

```
const [allRecordings , setAllRecordings ] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
allRecordings?allRecordings.map((item, index) => {
                   let cdate = item.recorded_dt;
                       var  d = cdate.split('T')[0];


                 return (


                  <tr key={(item.id)}>  
                    
                    <td>{ item.id}</td>
                    <td>{ (item.clientname) ? item.clientname : "n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.companyname) ? item.companyname : "n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.recorded_dt) ? d :"n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.file_length_min) ? item.file_length_min :"n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.signal_quality) ? item.signal_quality : "n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.HR_bpm) ? item.HR_bpm : "n/a" }</td>
                    <td>{ (item.name) ? item.name :"n/a" }</td>
                    <td><button onClick={() => this.fetchREcordingJson(item.id) }>View Recording</button> </td>
                    
                  </tr>  
                  

                  );

                } :""
```

Error clearly indicates that at some point your allrecordings is undefined that is why it is happening.

Comment: but need [] instead of " "